# Вывести arraylist картинок из вк

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Помогите вывести `ArrayList` картинок из вк. Одну картинку получаю, а `ArrayList` - не знаю как.

Получаю так:

```
public class RecyclerAdapterWall extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterWall.ViewHolder> {
    Context ctx;
    String owner_id;
    VKPostArray obj;
    Picasso picasso;
    private long longDate;


    public RecyclerAdapterWall(Context ctx, VKPostArray posts) {

        this.obj = posts;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public RecyclerAdapterWall(Context ctx, VKPostArray posts, String owner_id) {

        this.obj = posts;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.owner_id = owner_id;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            }
        });

        VKApiPost p = obj.get(position);

        try {

            VKAttachments att = new VKAttachments();
            att = p.attachments;
            VKApiPhoto photo = (VKApiPhoto) att.get(0);

            holder.imageWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imageWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                }

            });

            holder.textPost.setText(p.text);

            holder.news_name.setText(p.post_type);

            holder.textlikePost.setText(" " + p.likes_count);
            holder.textrepostPost.setText(" " + p.reposts_count);

            java.util.Date time = new java.util.Date((long) p.date * 1000);
            holder.textDatePost.setText(String.valueOf(time));

            picasso.with(ctx).load(photo.photo_604).into(holder.imageWall);
            //picasso.with(ctx).load().into(holder.news_ava);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return obj.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        Context ctx;
        CardView cv;
        TextView textlikePost;
        TextView textrepostPost;
        TextView textDatePost;
        TextView news_name;
        TextView textPost;
        ImageView imageWall, news_ava, like, repost;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_wall);

            news_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_name);
            textDatePost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatePost);
            textPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPost);
            imageWall = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageWall);

            news_ava = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_ava);

            textlikePost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_likes_count);
            textrepostPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_reposts_count);
            like = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_like);
            repost = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_repost);

        }}
    public void clear() {
        obj.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    }
```

Comment: э-э-э... Брать не по индексу 0, а пробежаться циклом по всем картинкам?...

Comment: for(i = 0; i < att.size(); i++){ Так что ли?

Comment: Типа того, да. Можно ещё так: `for (VKApiPhoto photo : att) {...}`

Comment: Или лучше просто изменить на: VKApiPhoto photo = (VKApiPhoto) att.size(); ?????

Comment: Так не получится - вы не сможете скастовать `int` к объекту. Вам нужен цикл

Comment: Спасибо..помогли...

Comment: а как все это дело запихнуть в GridView?

Comment: Ну... Создаёте адаптер, в него передаёте массив ссылок, в адаптере по ссылкам загружаете/отображаете картинки...

Comment: Какой массив ссылок? ведь photo же не массив

Comment: Вы слишком расплывчатый вопрос задали. Невозможно вам ответить иначе

Comment: просто не могу засунуть в GridView VKApiPhoto photo...

Comment: Ваше уточнение не прояснило суть вашей проблемы

Comment: Мне приходит одна картинка в ImageView, а я хочу чтобы приходил массив картинок в GridView, но не могу т.к незнаю как сделать массив картинок из VKApiPhoto photo

Comment: List< VKApiPhoto > list = new ArrayList<>(); list.add(photo);

Comment: Помогите еще разочек плизз.....ответ обновил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно,Я сделал так:

```
VKAttachments att = new VKAttachments();
att = p.attachments;
for(i = 0; i < att.size(); i++){
    VKApiPhoto photo = (VKApiPhoto) att.get(i); 

    List<VKApiPhoto> mSmallPhotoUrls = new ArrayList<>();
            mSmallPhotoUrls.add(vkPhoto);

            List<String> imgUrls = new ArrayList<>(mSmallPhotoUrls.size());
            imgUrls.add(vkPhoto.photo_604);
}
```

А в imgUrls приходит все ровно одна картинка....помогите разобраться

Comment: Вы каждый раз создаёте новый список с фотками/ссылками. Итого он у вас длиной в один элемент. Вынесите создание список за пределы цикла, а в цикле их наполняйте

Comment: можете показать!!! ато уже каторый день долблюсь над этим....нечего уже не соображаю.... заранее благодарен

Comment: аааааа....спасибо огромное!!! получилось...

Comment: а вот еще вопросец!!! Вот в ответе, как сделано выходит одна картинка и она соответствует этой новости!!! А если я выношу создание списка картинок на пределы цикла, то они начинают быть где попало!!! такое исправляется?

Comment: каким размером должен приходить attachment с вк? (я про size() ???? пример: vkPhoto = (VKApiPhoto) att.get(0);)

Comment: По идее это должно быть в доке к АПИ описано. По идее этих картинок должно быть разное кол-во, в зависимости от поста.